# Returning days/months since latest post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, entity

I have this in my controller:

```
    model.LatestPosts = db.TPGForumPosts.Select(v => v).OrderByDescending(d => 
d.dateCreated).Take(5);
```

This gives me the 5 latest posts.

I am going to display them on my cshtml page.

Is there an easy way to convert the date to days/months since today?

```
A cold hard truth by jwilson posted 5 days ago
A cold hard fact by jwilson posted 3 months ago
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use some jQuery and the timeago plugin: http://timeago.yarp.com/

Your view would need to look something like this:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.timeago.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options for this. If you want to go client side then TimeAgo or [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/from/) are good options. To do this in .Net you can use [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/) which is a great date/time library for .NET.